# Firefox not rendering fonts: What is usually the root of the issue?

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, fonts

I wanted the font `open_sansregular` from [this](http://www.catholicdos.org/stewardship) site and so I downloaded local copies of the fonts in their different encodings (except for the `svg` ones and the `iefix` ones), put them in the same folder as my CSS file, and copied the org's `@font-face` definitions

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'open_sansregular';
  src: url('/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_bold_macroman/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_bold_macroman/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_bold_macroman/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_bold_macroman/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_bold_macroman/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#open_sansbold') format('svg');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'open_sansregular';
  src: url('/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

but changed them paths to local ones where appropriate:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'open_sansregular';
  src: url('OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('http://www.catholicdos.org/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_bold_macroman/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('OpenSans-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://www.catholicdos.org/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_bold_macroman/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#open_sansbold') format('svg');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'open_sansregular';
  src: url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('http://www.catholicdos.org/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://www.catholicdos.org/resources/fonts/opensans/web fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

The fonts are rendering in Chrome but not Firefox. I know that Firefox reads the `ttf` files and I don't see why they aren't being rendered. I've experienced this problem sometimes and other times not, so I don't know why this sometimes happens. Can someone give me a list of potential problems I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your path contains a space char in the `web fonts` directory, you need to encode it. Replace the space with a `%20`, so it ends up looking like this...

```
src: url('http://www.catholicdos.org/resources/fonts/opensans/web%20fonts/opensans_regular_macroman/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
```

(or better yet, rename the directory `web-fonts` if you are certain you won't break anything)

Comment: Good to know, though it doesn't fix the problem I was having